# staruml abstract classes?

Tags: uml

does anyone know how to create an abstract class using StarUML? I couldnt find any mention in the documentation.

Is there some sort of more general concept which mirrors an abstract class?

Comment: This tutorial creates an abstract class. http://cnx.org/content/m15092/latest/

Comment: Thanks! To anyone reading, in the properties panel you need to tick 'IsAbstract'

Answer (score 7):

select class from toolBox and add it to canvas, then go to properties select isAbstract checkbox.

then class name appears italic.

[image: Properties window]

Answer (score 3):

Migrated from comment

This tutorial creates an abstract class. 
http://cnx.org/content/m15092/latest

Comment: I see no abstract class there only interfaces with implicitly abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

View menu > select Editors > select class name and/or method in class diagram  >  Poperty window > select isAbstract > you'll see your class name and/or method in italics