# How to show this class in a UML diagram?

Tags: java, uml

How to show this class in a UML diagram?

```
    abstract class Point{
abstract String getXPoint();
abstract String getYPoint();
   }
```

Comment: With a gorgeous smile! (or else your audience will notice that you use Strings for numerical content and you will get slapped back to the middle ages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803974/staruml-abstract-classes

Comment: getXPoint() is return a place man. I mean a string content.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12636575/1317692

Comment: Java class diagram not c#.

Comment: UML is not language dependent... Also, if they return proper strings, then the names are incorrect and misleading. As it misled me, it will misled others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, With `<<abstract>>` next to the class name, an inheritance mapping (if any class implements it) and the method declaration in italic and bold.

Also, I've seen many diagrams that take the poetic license of explicitly adding *abstract* before the method's name but I'd stick to pure UML.

```
 ______________________
|     <<abstract>>     |
|        Point         |
|______________________|
| +getXPoint(): String |
| +getYPoint(): String |
|______________________|
```

Note: I assume your abstract methods are public.